# If Japan won WWII, why would they write from right to left and in kyujitai form?

Tags: realism, historical-accuracy, the-man-in-the-high-castle

Can someone please expound the following comment based on the screenshot below? I don't speak Japanese, so please forgive my benightedness. How does Japan's imaginary winning World War II affect Japanese's

1. written word order?
2. [kyujitai](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74086/30835) form?

> [0:22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhdQtwZDkGs&t=22s) the Japanese on the soldiers’ hats were written from right to left and in kyujitai form (國 instead of 国). Such changes would’ve never happened had Japan not been defeated as seen here. I love the attention to details in this show.

[image]

Comment: How do you know for sure these changes would never happen? Can you [edit] the question to add some evidence?

Comment: A [quick google search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai) suggests that "kyujitai" (meaning "old character form") is the traditional way of writing kanji going back who knows how long, and "shinjitai" ("new character form") are the more recent, simplified kanji that *merely* date back "for centuries" in some cases. I'm certainly no expert, but I think you need to do a lot more research on this topic before assuming that Japan winning or losing the war had anything to do with this.